# TypeScript: @types package name does not match implementation package name

Tags: typescript

What do you do when the npm package containing the typings does not match the name of the package containing the implementation?

For example, [`@types/filesaver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/filesaver) contains the type definitions for FileSaver.js, whose npm package name is [`file-saver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

Background info: [the future of declaration files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, you can `git mv` the folder in DefinitelyTyped and send us a pull request to the `types-2.0` branch (or whichever branch hosts the state of `@types`). I've done this for you [with this pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12507).

In the mean time, you can add the `"types"` field to your `tsconfig.json`'s `"compilerOptions"` field, and set it to `["filesaver"]`. This will tell TypeScript to load in the declaration for you so that you can correctly import `file-saver`.

Here's an example of how it should look:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "types": ["filesaver"]
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! thanks for this and all your contributions to definitelytyped

Comment: Does this strategy still work nowadays? I cannot get it to work with Typescript 3.2.2